# What's DNS suffix when configuring the Lab Environment in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to set up my Lab Environment with TFS.

I already have SCVMM server and hyper-v hosts.

But when i configure Lab Environment in TFS, it requires DNS suffix in Network Isolation tab.

What's DNS suffix and Where can i find it?

I'm in a domain which controlled by another one. So if it's info entry from Domain Controller, does that mean i have to set up my private domain environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it the DNS suffix of your primary domain.  Even though you may end up setting up private domains within you lab environment, the DNS suffix you provide there is the publicly addressable one that you will use to connect/route into your Lab environments from MTM and your dev machines.